# No longer able to install Charles SSL Certificate on tvOS 12 Simulator

Tags: xcode, ssl-certificate, tvos, xcode10, charles-proxy

Since the release of tvOS 12, I can't seem to figure out how to add a certificate to my tvOS Simulator. Here's the usual steps I take for tvOS 11:

1. Navigate to **Settings** > **General** > **Privacy** and select **Share Apple TV Analytics**
2. Press the **Play/Pause** button on the remote; this brings up a screen that lists the installed profiles along with an **Add Profile** option at the top
3. Choose **Add Profile**
4. Enter the URL of the profile and follow the on-screen instructions to complete the install process
5. URL: **https://chls.pro/ssl**
6. Go through the steps of installing the **Charles Profile**
7. After installing the profile, we need to *Trust the certificate*.
8. Navigate to **Settings** > **General** > **About** > **Certificates**
9. Select **Charles Certificate (Not Trusted)**
10. Set to **Trusted**

Comment: Did you see **tvOS** section on their *SSL Certificates* docs page? https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Comment: Ok, I tried the iOS simulator method and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Following steps worked for me.

1. Save charles root certificate from the charles-> Help-> ssl proxying
2. Drag and drop the downloded .pem certificate in your tvOS simulator.
3. Check in TvOS settings, General-> About-> Certificate Trust settings (It should appear after drag and dropping certificate in simulator and downloading the certificate in the tvOS simulator).
4. Make sure the certificate is trusted.

And Voila, its done.

Answer (score 4):

Found my answer by following iOS Simulators guide on their SSL Certificates docs page.

1. Quit your **iOS Simulator**.
2. Launch **Charles** and go to the **Help** menu.
3. Choose the "**SSL Proxying** > **Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators**" item.

This will install your Charles Root Certificate into all of your iOS Simulators. Now when you start the iOS Simulator, you should be able to access SSL websites with Charles using SSL Proxying.

[Source](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/)